# numpy array manipulation :why the address of a numpy array not same as the address of its subset after splice

Tags: python, numpy

When i am trying to create a numpy array and i tired manipulating it using splicing .ideals spliced array and original array should remain same but it is not .Why?

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
```

i have taken this array
i will splice now and update its value

```
c = a[:2,1:3]
c[0,0] = 99
```

now the value of a also gets updated at its respective position
in python this happens only when the address is same

when i am checking id of each it shows different

```
print(id(c),id(a))
```

output :

```
139866833241552 139866835761152
```

Comment: `c` is a `view` of `a`.  It is a different object, hance the djfferent `id`.  `id` tells us nothing about shaped data-buffer (bass).  Don't skip the 'numpy for beginners' intro docs.

Comment: I just commented on another use of `id`, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285640/how-numpy-arrays-are-stored-in-memory-locations

Answer (score 0):

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> c=a[:2,1:3]
>>> c
array([[2, 3],
       [7, 9]])
>>> c[0,0]
2
>>> c[0,0]=99
>>> c
array([[99,  3],
       [ 7,  9]])
>>> a
array([[ 1, 99,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Your question is why is a reflecting changes in c?

1. Because c and a are pointing to the same object
2. To make a copy of a, you create a new object

as below-

`````
>>> a
array([[ 1, 99,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> c=np.array(a)
>>> c
array([[ 1, 99,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> c[0,0]=100
>>> c
array([[100,  99,   3,   4,   5],
       [  6,   7,   9,  10,  11]])
>>> a
array([[ 1, 99,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  9, 10, 11]])````
`````

Comment: `c` is a different array object, with its own shape.  But it is a `view`.  That's an important concept in numpy.