# Overwriting Numpy Array Memory In-Place

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am looking for validation that overwriting a numpy array with `numpy.zeros` overwrites the array at the location(s) in memory where the original array's elements are stored.

The [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/c-api/data_memory.html) discusses this, but it seems I don't have enough background to understand whether just setting new values with the zeros function will overwrite the location in-place. One question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865995/using-memset-instead-of-np-zeros-in-a-cython-script-for-speed-gains) appears to indicate that it does. On the other hand, if I am interpreting the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285640/how-numpy-arrays-are-stored-in-memory-locations) question correctly, it may not.

Comment: Most numpy functions will return a new array object, such as zeros(). If you want to overwrite the elements of an existing array, you need to do so with direct assignment (e.g. array[:] = 0).

Comment: Your first link, 'documentation' is meant for C-API users, and the second for `cython`, so are of limited value to you.  All my answer in the last link tells you is how to identify "where" the data is stored.  None tell you what operations modify the existing data as opposed to returning a new array.

Comment: Why are you concerned about this?  It's important to know when an operation returns a new array versus modifying an existing one.  Closely related it knowing when the result is a `view` versus `copy`.  But trying to "overwrite" to save time, or conserve memory, is an advanced topic.  Also operations may create temporary arrays, that are later removed when whole assignment is done.

Comment: @hpaulj In this case, I am trying to ensure that the array does not persist beyond a certain point in the program, anywhere on the machine. I don't want data fragments remaining anywhere on the hardware.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, but then I'm not an expert on how `numpy`, `python` and the OS together manage memory.  Is some sort of 'security' concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to overwrite an existing NumPy array's memory with `numpy.zeros`. `numpy.zeros` does not offer such functionality. If you thought you were doing that, you most likely had code like

```
existing_array_name = numpy.zeros(...)
```

which does not clear the existing array's memory. It creates a new array.

If you want to zero out an array's elements, use

```
array[...] = 0
```

For reference, NumPy functions that *do* let you overwrite an existing array's memory usually do so by taking that array as an `out` parameter. For example, you can add the elements of two arrays `a` and `b` and write the result into an existing array `c` by doing

```
numpy.add(a, b, out=c)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! So, if you were trying to overwrite a numpy array to zeros, I could use something like: numpy_array *= 0.0?

Comment: @wb1210: That fails if any elements are infinities or NaNs. `array[...] = 0` handles those cases, and also more directly displays the intent.

Comment: The `*=0` approach is slower.  It is approximately, `temp=arr*0.0; arr[:]=temp`, creating a temporary buffer.